# How to configure Burp Suite for localhost application

Tags: burp-suite

I am trying to analyze HTTP traffic of our application. Application uses port **8080**. So I had configured burp proxy for **6666** and upstream proxy to our organisation proxy.

Made changes to browser's proxy for **127.0.0.1:6666** application URL can be reached to **127.0.0.1:8080**

But from browser I get **"proxy server is refusing connections"** for application landing page.

How to configure burp to work with local apps running on 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. In Burp go to Proxy / Options / Proxy listeners, and confirm the Running box is ticked.
2. In proxy tab make sure intercept is turned off.
3. Make sure the proxy in burp listener is 127.0.0.1:6666.
4. Configure your browser to use 127.0.0.1:6666 as its proxy.
5. Configure Burp to use your original LAN proxy (from your original browser configs) as its upstream proxy.
6. Run your browser and access your application.

Update:
Additional reasons could be browser restricted ports. You mentioned you are using Firefox. Try this.

1. Type the following into Firefox address bar 'about:config'
2. Type the following settings 'network.security.ports.banned.override'
3. Enter your port number '6666'

Comment: It is working now at some other port. Looks like 6666 port had some issue even though proxy was running. changed port to 7878 and everything is fine now.

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. Are you using chrome?

Comment: Nope. I am using Firefox. Even though port proxy was running at 6666 with proxy listening ticked. Browser was unable to connect. But it works fine with port 7878. Are there comprehensive logs available for burp tools

Comment: Port 6666 could be in the firefox restricted ports. I've edited the answers to include the "how to" to override the restrictions.

Comment: Yeah. It is restricted port. Didn't check that.

Comment: cool. Google chrome has its fair share of restricted ports too

Comment: Here is a nice link showing Restricted ports on Google Chrome and some related info: https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-by-chrome

Answer (score 19):

If none of these solutions work for you, like they didn't work for me, you could try to change value `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` to `true` (using firefox v 67.0.1 64-bit).

Open new tab, type `about:config` in address bar, then type `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` and double click it to change its default value to `true`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's Mozilla who is actually blocking all traffic towards localhost

Comment: This happened to me today. Firefox 79.0. This setting worked.

Comment: Depending on what you're working with, you may also want to set "network.proxy.testing_localhost_is_secure_when_hijacked" to true. Otherwise any apps that use Web Cryptography API will fail (e.g. if you use auth0-spa-js or something)

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a '.' after "localhost". This should solve your problem.

eg.

http://localhost.:8080/WebGoat/
This will force the localhost to use the same proxy settings as one would with an internet connection/adapter

Comment: Yeah, it worked. But, did not at first. After I removed Firefox and Burpsuite installations completely and install them again, dot solution coming after localhost domain name in url address bar worked.

Comment: it works like a charm, be sure to add something after port number ex `localhost.:3000/some_url` or it will be search for it online

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem very simply.

```
Firefox -> options -> network proxy ->
select on manual proxy configuration -> 
set the config shown in the image -> 
then clear the text area called "No proxy for" -> save
```

[image]

Comment: This does not address the port number issue. You do not explain how clearing this field helps. What was in there before?

Comment: The comments under the accepted answer explain what the problem was, and it wasn't this ...

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to follow to Intercept Localhost Traffic with Burp Suite Mozilla Firefox:**

1. Go to Mozilla and type **about:config**

**[image]**

2. Accept the risk and continue.

[image]

3. Now, search **network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost** and set the value from false to **true**

[image]

4. Send request from the localhost, it will start intercepting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using IE.
Go to: Internet Options -> LAN Settings -> Uncheck "Bypass proxy server for local address".

Answer (score 0):

There are quite many steps to set Burp Suite working on `localhost`, for example, to run this on `Firefox` you might need:

1. `Burp`'s certificate accessible via `http://burp`. Get the certificate from the URL, install and restart `Firefox`.
2. Make sure your port is free, sometimes the default's `8080` is being used by different applications. Change this in `Burp Suite` -> `Proxy` -> `Options` -> `Edit` on the desired proxy listener.
3. Set up the same proxy details in `Firefox` having the `Manual proxy configuration` option enabled, which you can see in `Burp Suite` -> `Proxy` -> `Options`.
4. In `Firefox` you might need type `about:config` in the URL and set `network.security.ports.banned.override` to `PORT_NUMBER` (the same one which is in `Burp Suite` -> `Proxy` -> `Options` -> `Edit` and therefore in `Firefox`'s proxy - yes, point 3.).
5. In `Firefox` you might need type `about:config` in the URL and set `network.proxy.allow.hijacking_localhost` to `true`.
6. Sometimes you might need to read more about **upstream proxy** if you have an additional proxy on your local machine, however in my case it was not required.